# Copy Files in VSTS just doesn't work from dSYM files

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have setup Xamarin.IOS continuaous intergration with Visual Studio Team Services to publish ipa. But when I want to publish dSym files, the Copy Files action just doesn't recognize the pattern, even when I use exact path.

I have those patterns:

```
2016-08-28T05:33:42.6657530Z ##[debug]include content pattern: **/*.dsym
2016-08-28T05:33:42.6670550Z ##[debug]include content pattern: **/*.ipa
2016-08-28T05:33:42.6680380Z ##[debug]include content pattern: **/*.config
```

For ipa and config files, it works, but just doesn't for dsym.

```
2016-08-28T05:33:42.6799920Z ##[debug]Include matching /Users/myname/myagent/_work/2/s/appName/bin/iPhone/Release/**/*.dsym
2016-08-28T05:33:42.6885670Z ##[debug]Include matched 0 files
```

I even tried exact match, still no luck. Does anyone know why is this?

Comment: You're probably pointing to the wrong directory.

Comment: @DanielMann it's in the same directory as ipa and config, they all get copied. If I use "**", then everything gets copied including dSYM files.

Comment: What's the result if you specify the name directly?

Comment: @starain the same, it's not copying. This surprises me the most, since it's exact match.

Answer (score 3):

The same root cause as this issue: [dSYM file missing in Xamarin iOS app in VSTS](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1983).

> The .dSYM is being generated but it is a folder and not a single file
>   and the test cloud task is looking for files, so it is not picking it
>   up.

So you need to use "**" as a work around for now.

Comment: When I build in VSTS, it's generated as a file with extension .dSYM. I don't think it's the same issue.

Comment: Wait, this may be it. Since sometime you can't tell if it's a folder or not in Mac. Let me check when I get home and confirm back.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue! It shows as "package" on mac, but it's actual a folder. Thanks!

Comment: @zhankezk no problem. :)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add this as a comment above but it kept messing up the formatting.

The Git [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/1983#issuecomment-267677398) linked to in that answer shows how to do it. Just use

```
**/*.dSYM/**
```