# VSTS - CI-CD pipeline using Hosted Mac

Tags: ios, build, azure-devops

I am trying to use Hosted Mac option in VSTS for building my IOS app.Currently i am facing a problem in getting the .app file after the build.Below are the screen shots of my configuration for build

After the build completes i am not able to get the .app files.Below are my xcode Build options

```
steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode build'
  inputs:
    xcWorkspacePath: 'platforms/ios/*.xcworkspace'

    scheme: myfirstapp

    packageApp: true

    archivePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy'

    exportPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy'

    exportOptions: specify

    exportMethod: enterprise

    exportTeamId: AL97FW9WY7

    signingOption: manual

    signingIdentity: myfirstapp

    provisioningProfileUuid: myfirstapp

    provisioningProfileName: myfirstapp
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say *i am not able to get the .app files*? Do you have a Publish Artifacts task pointing to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy`?

Comment: i have the publish artifacts but the copyfile is not able to fetch the .app files.Based on the build the file is getting placed in "/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myfirstapp-faheusxfaiphfdcxpseprqquwjfd/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/myfirstapp.app" this folder and in copy files task i used "/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myfirstapp-dxfbcyfukiuxreeidlapgwscubln/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/myfirstapp.app" but nothing copied

Comment: @Jaffarsadiq Have you built the project successfully? Seems it's the contents copy pattern issue. It's similar as this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188375/copy-files-in-vsts-just-doesnt-work-from-dsym-files. So just try to use "`**`" as the pattern.

Comment: @Jaffar sadiq, Since it was resolved, if possible, you could mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved.in Hosted mac when we try to copy .app file from mac its considering it as a folder rather than a File.I tried ** and copied whole folder to Artifacts Drop folder